# php check empty syntax error

Tags: php, syntax

What's wrong?

I can not figure out how to check whether the two variables are empty.

I created this:

it's right?

```
if (empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])&&($username=$_POST['username'])){
    $query3=mysql_query("update addd set name='$name', email='$email', age='$age' where id='$id'");
};
```

Comment: Is the single equal sign a mistake? `$username=$_POST['username']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to use empty in `$username=$_POST['username']` and try to assign value in `$username` after checking

Try like this

```
if (empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])&& empty($_POST['username'])) {
}
```